# Issues in migrating jsFiddle to asp.net VS IDE : table datagrid not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0, jquery-easyui

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3j1rqbap/1)

I am moving this code into ASP.Net using Visual Studio 2013. Assuming there are cart data that user saved into the database and they want to see it again when returned. So I want to populate the cart's table datagrid. The data is prepared from codebehind using C# and the array is serialized to javascript using following code. The array is successfully passed onto javascript.

```
var arrList = new List<object>();

        string x = string.Empty;
        int i = table.Rows.Count;
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            string name = row[0].ToString();
            string quantity = row[1].ToString();
            string price = row[2].ToString();
            string remove = "X";

            arrList.Add(new [] {name, quantity, price, remove});
        }

        return (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(arrList);
```

While doing so, the following function `loadData` uses this array (e.g. data[]) to load the table using `table.datagrid.loadData()`.

```
function loadData(cartIndex, event) {
    var $cart = $('.news:eq(' + cartIndex + ')');
    alert(data[cartIndex]);
    $cart.find('.cartcontent').datagrid('loadData', data[cartIndex]);    
    $cart.find('.total').text('Total: $' + data[cartIndex].total);
}
```

However this function doesn't seem to load the table. What's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

In one aspect, server side code behind C# code isn't able to *make* an array structure that's identical to what's created in jquery/javascript. That's what this exercise taught me. I may be wrong, because this is my first and longest experiment in learning the implementation of jquery/javascript arrays, serializing an array structure from C# into the client side.

On the other hand, there's nothing wrong with above jquery function. As long as the data is available and array is in right structure for the basis of the function's access code, it does populate the html table datagrid.

However a major step in getting all these done, is to make sure that these functions are called only after DOM elements are fully loaded. At least in this scenario that was a hidden issue.